# Increase/decrease play speed of a WAV file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Hello I need help in MATLAB.
My wave file plays with this code:

```
x=wavread('D:\\Sample.wav');
```

Now I want to increase/decrease the play speed of a WAV file in MATLAB with `reshape`. For example, double the speed.

Let me to Explain it .
when We use this code:

```
x=wavread('D:\\\Sample.wav');
```

now x is a Matrix 92086 * 1
and now I want to set zero for Decussate of X Like this:

```
0
value1
0
value2
...
...
```

now how can i do it whit **reshape**?

After that, I need to merge two WAV files into one WAV file. For example I have two files:

```
  x=wavread('D:\\Sample1.wav');
  y=wavread('D:\\Sample2.wav');
```

and need to merge these and play it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean to use the [`resample`](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) and not the `reshape` function. `reshape` is used to (well..) reshape a matrix, i.e. change the number of rows and columns. The `resample` function can be used to change the sampling rate of a signal. You can use this to increase / decrease the play speed of your WAV file. The syntax of `resample` is:

```
y = resample(x,p,q);
```

where `x` is the input signal, `p` is the desired sampling rate and `q` is the current sampling rate. The output `y` is then the input `x`, resampled at `p/q` times the original rate.

Now how can we double the speed? - If we set `p=2` and `q=1` we get a resampled signal at double the sampling rate, i.e. we have twice as many samples. If you play the WAV with the same command, then the signal takes twice as long to play, so we divided the play speed by 2.

To double the play speed, we'll have to do the opposite and set  `p=1` and `q=2`:

```
x = wavread('D:\\Sample.wav');
y = resample(x,1,2);
```

--

As requested in an edit, it is of course possible to add zeros e.g. at every second position to change the sampling rate. Note that this creates high-frequency noise, which is usually removed by FIR-filtering. The procedure however is quite easy:

```
x = x(:).';                  % Make x a row vector
y = [x; zeros(1,numel(x))];  % add one zero between elements
y = y(:);
```

The last row does the magic here: it takes the columns of `y` and stacks them above each other. As `x` was one row, and we added a row of zeros below that, the resulting `y` will be a row containing all elements of `x` with zeros between the values.

As you specifically wanted to use `reshape`, we can do the same using reshape:

```
x = x(:).';                  % Make x a row vector
y = [x; zeros(1,numel(x))];  % add one zero between elements
y = reshape(y,[],1);
```

--

To merge two WAV files into one, we can simply concatenate the vectors using the `[...]` notation or the `cat` function.

```
x = wavread('D:\\Sample1.wav');
y = wavread('D:\\Sample2.wav');

z = [x,y];
z = cat(2,x,y);
```

Comment: Give me a little time to check out

Comment: No this is Reshape ant not Resample

Comment: Thank you. I added a part on that in the middle of my answer. Does this help you?

Comment: @FarshadKhodamoradi, *why* do you want to use `reshape`? It really doesn't make that much sense; hbadert's first answer is spot on.